# GCS and Blobstore virus scans and limiting file types

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

We currently use the blobstore to handle user uploads (and will likely shift to GCS). Our solution allows users to upload files but I've recently found that users could potentially upload a virus (knowingly or unknowingly).To mitigate this risk I'm considering limiting file types to images and/or pdfs (this would be checked server side). Would this prevent a virus from being uploaded or should I also perform a virus scan on the files once they're uploaded?
If running a virus scan, is there a simple for solution for doing this with GAE or do I need a separate cloud compute instance running it's own virus scan?

Thanks
Rob

Comment: For virus scanning your best bet is to use some external APIs. It's really depends on your use case. If you can allow users to upload only pictures and PDF – of course you should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you delegate authority to upload an object to an untrusted client, there is risk that the client or malicious code posing as the client can upload malicious content. As far as I am aware, neither Google App Engine's Blobstore service nor Google Cloud Storage provide virus scanning as a service, so you'd have to bring your own. Limiting file types doesn't actually inhibit bad content being uploaded, as some browsers will ignore the stated file type after sniffing file content and render or execute the malicious object.

If you want to do this yourself for a Google Cloud Storage upload, the best practice would be to restrict the upload to have a private ACL, perform whatever sanitization you want, and when determined to be valid, change the ACL to allow broader permissions.

/via [Vinny P](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/Uq8bhl28Yvk/tcNyMkf9DJkJ): 
There are online virus-scanning tools you can use programmatically, or you can run an anti-virus engine on Compute Engine or in an [App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/). Alternatively, if these are supposed to be user-owned files under 25 MB, you could [upload the files to Google Drive](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172541?hl=en) which will provide virus scanning, and [retrieve the files via the Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/).

Comment: Cool, was thinking about the gdrive upload to handle scans.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to automatically scan files in GCS for viruses: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/automating-malware-scanning-for-documents-uploaded-to-cloud-storage